# MyBatis association error

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have three objects: A, B and C. A contains B and B contains C.
I need to load some atributtes from all the three. Bellow is my select:
I can successfully load A and B, but when I try to load C (bold lines), I get the following error:

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for B"

Any idea how I can fix this?

I'm using MyBatis 3.1.1 with Spring and Maven

```
<select id="loadA" resultMap="AResult">
     SELECT * FROM A a, B b, C c
     where a.lae_ree_cod=b.ree_cod      
     and b.ree_rea_cod=c.rea_cod            
</select>   

<resultMap id="AResult" type="A">
        <id property="A_Cod" column="cod" />
        <result property="A_Descricao" column="descricao"/>
        <result property="A_DataInclusao" column="datainclusao"/>
        <association property="B_Executada" resultMap="BResult"     />                              
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="BResult" type="B">
        <id property="B_cod" column="cod"/>
        <result property="B_voltou" column="voltou"/>
        **<association property="C_Executada" resultMap="CResult"   />**                
</resultMap>

**<resultMap id="CResult" type="C">
        <id property="C_cod" column="cod"/> 
</resultMap>**
```

Comment: what about loteAcaoEletronicaResult?

Comment: This error usually means that you have syntactically incorrect mapping file. In this case you have some weird stars `**`. Have you copied the file verbatim here?

Comment: Another problem (probably unrelated but still will make this mapping unusable) is that all tables have `cod` column so result set will contain duplicate columns and mapping may to not work correctly. One way to overcome this is to prefix table columns as described in mybatis manual.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was the Hibernate tags from my model class.